# Is it possible to identify the person talking to the google assistant by voice?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, actions-on-google

Recently google has added multiple user support to the assistant so how would use the API to identify the person by voice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "identify the person".

There is no way for an Action to get the raw audio, so there is no way for it to do voice printing or anything along those lines.

Although each voice has to be reported against a Google User ID, you do not have direct access to that user ID.

What developers do have access to is a [UID](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/AppRequest#User) that is sent along with each request to your fulfillment server. This UID is consistent across requests, although it can be reset by a user (for example, if they reset their Google Home). You can think of this the same way you think of an HTTP cookie - you can track the UID and, if you see it again, have reasonable assurance it is the same user that accessed it last time. This breaks down, however, for the "default" account on Google Home, since anybody who doesn't have an account will map to this user.

Beyond this, you can also use [Account Linking](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/) to connect a Google Account consistently to an account in your own system. If you have sufficient authentication in place, or are using one from Google or Facebook for example, this can act as an identity.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an API for developers to identify users by voice.